# git - diff of current changes before committing

Tags: git, ssh, diff, meld

I have changed several files in a git repository, but have not committed them yet.

I can get a list of the changes by just invoking `git status`. But how do I get a listing of the *lines* or the *content* that I have changed, in addition to the filenames?

I initially thought about using [git diff](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-diff.html), but it seems to be useful only for comparing already commited changes.

Usually I just do `meld .`, but on this case I'm connected to an external server via ssh.

Answer (score 193, accepted):

`git diff` by default shows difference between your *working directory* and the *index* (*staging area* for the next commit).

If you have already added (*staged*) the changes to the *staging area*, `git diff --staged` does the job.  *Staging area* is the data from which the next commit will be formed by `git commit`.

P. S. Good reading (IMO) for Git beginners:

- https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2 (most chapters; it explains the model behind Git and answers most of typical questions)
- and then immediately http://gitready.com/ (usage tips).

Comment: Doesn't staged only apply to files not added yet? Thought you had to use the cached flag.

Comment: @peterbond `man git-diff` says `--staged is a synonym of --cached`

Comment: @peterbond Technically *staged* means *added to the staging area* which is not yet a commit.  I have clarified that in the edit.

Comment: @Mischa The [documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-diff) says  that the default behaviour for `git diff` is to compute the difference between the working directory and **the index**, not `HEAD`

Comment: It didn't occur to me to invoke git diff with no params. Thanks!

Answer (score 23):

What i use for such cases is:

```
git diff HEAD *
```

This will show the changes since last commit. Although somehow it works quicker with

```
git diff .
```

or

```
git diff
```

To see the changes on previously `git add`ed files, use the `staged` flag:

```
git diff --staged
```